# YARN Memory Allocation Parameters

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2, cloudera-cdh

I'm working on configuring our CDH cluster for YARN (currently we use MR1).  I've been trying to wrap my head around all the yarn memory parameters, to make sure we're fully utilizing our machines and ended up diagramming it:

[image: YARN Node Memory Breakdown]

We use Cloudera manager, so I've included relevant CDM settings and processes, which won't apply to every cluster.

My question: am I missing any configurable memory-allocation parameters, or am I interpreting any incorrectly?  I've had trouble parsing the documentation, and want to avoid any trial-and-error possible.

Comment: you may want to consider yarn.nodemanager.vmem-pmem-ratio